# graphic interface java insert space for image

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, graphics

Good morning,I am currently trying to make a graphic user interface like this:

[image]

I would want to have 3 blank spaces for images and under each blank space, a button to choose and load an image. I've been reading tutorials and so on, with paintingComponent and so, but I don't know how to make these blank spaces and buttons and open a window to choose from you computer the images when we click on load.

I have written this:

```
package projet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameIM extends JFrame{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7538888128782793269L;
private static final int width = 700;
private static final int height = 500;

public FrameIM(){
    //window
    this.setTitle("Mutual information");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(width, height);

    //boutons
    JButton boutonLoad1 = new JButton("Load image A");
    JButton boutonLoad2 = new JButton("Load image B");
    JButton boutonProcess = new JButton("Processing Mutual information");

    //layout des boutons
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 200));
    //ajout des boutons
    this.getContentPane().add(boutonLoad1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.getContentPane().add(boutonLoad2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(boutonProcess, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.setVisible(true);

}`
```

If someone can help me, I would appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to be rude. I asked a question obviously because someone answered me. The last sentence was a polite sentence only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to take an action with your buttons, you need to implement [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) interface, like:

```
//boutons
    JButton boutonLoad1 = new JButton("Load image A");
    boutonLoad1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("button 1 is pressed");
        }
    });
    ... do same with your other buttons
```

According to your prototype image, you will need to play around with [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I will give you instructions, as I imagined it could be done with [Grid Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid), in order to achieve what you need:

Create your primary JPanel with BoxLayout and set it to Y_AXIS, and at the end add it to your ContentPane

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

Now you'll create and add three more panels to your main panel:

You first (north) panel, which will contain your Labels, will be:

```
int rows = 0;
int cols = 3;
int hgap = 5; 
int vgap = 0;
JPanel first = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows,cols,hgap,vgap));
```

Your second (center) panel, which will contain your Images, will be:

```
int rows = 0;
int cols = 3;
int hgap = 10;
int vgap = 10;
JPanel second = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows,cols,hgap,vgap));
```

Third (south) panel which will contain your Buttons, will be:

```
int rows = 0;
int cols = 3;
int hgap = 5;
int vgap = 0;
JPanel third = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows,cols,hgap,vgap));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to take an action when a button is pressed you need to add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).  Inside there you can open a [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to let the user choose a file.